# Showing intervals as Range rather than Upper Value using ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-pro, labeling, symbology

I'm trying to show my point data with intervals but in ArcGIS Pro I only get "Upper value" which I don't want.

In ArcMap it looks like this:

[image]

but in ArcGIS Pro it looks like this:

[image]

How can I list the point data with intervals like I can in ArcMap?

---

I am using ArcGIS Pro 2.4.0 and it seems that this issue is fixed in later updates.

Comment: Both way seem quite similar to me, the main difference beeing that ArcGis PRO show only the upper value of the interval . You probably could edit the label to show the lower and upper value

Comment: Well yes that is the question: how do I do that?

Comment: Just click on the label you want to modify and type what you need...

Comment: That could work but I have to do it manually? If I didn't have ArcMap I wouldn't know what numbers to put in.

Comment: Upper value of one class is lower value of next class...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not say what version of ArcGIS Pro you are using but I think it must be earlier than 2.7 because there is an ArcGIS Idea named [ArcGIS Pro - more Intuitive Default Legend Labels](https://community.esri.com/t5/arcgis-pro-ideas/arcgis-pro-more-intuitive-default-legend-labels/idi-p/971418) that I believe was implemented at 2.7 to address it.

I just did a quick test at ArcGIS Pro 2.8 and got this as my result (with no manual intervention):

[image]

Comment: Aha. I have 2.4 version which is from my university. It don't think it lets me update "Download now" is greyed out for me. But thanks for answering, my solution will be to import from ArcMap then.